# Encode a model properties in to a query URL parameters

Tags: swift, url-parameters, query-string, codable

I have a model with a lot of properties i want to Encode this model in url query parameters.

```
public typealias Parameters = [String : Any]

enum ProductWriteApi {
   case addOFFProduct(product: OFFProduct)
}

extension ProductWriteApi: EndPointType {
   var parameters: Parameters {
    switch self {
    case .addOFFProduct(let product):
        var parameters: Parameters!
        do {
            //Need to encode the product model to be like the Example parameters down there.
            let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(product)
            //This data wont be sent in the body. It will be sent in the URL.
        } catch {

        }
        //Example parameters needed
        parameters = [
            "name": "Cereal",
            "categorie": "Milks"
        ]

        return parameters
    }
  }
}
```

So how can i change/encode my products model to a `[String : Any]` to be able to loop through them and add them in my url string.
Or do i have to pass by each product property one by one and check if it is not `nil` nor empty and add it to a `[String : Any]` type variable?

Or is there another simpler solution that i have no idea about?

This is the static function that adds parameters to my url by looping through the parameters and appending them in the query items.

```
public struct URLParameterEncoder: ParameterEncoder {

 public static func encode(urlRequest: inout URLRequest, with parameters: Parameters) throws {
    guard let url = urlRequest.url else { throw NetworkError.missingURL}

    if var urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) {
        urlComponents.queryItems = [URLQueryItem]()

        for (key,value) in parameters {
            let queryItem = URLQueryItem(name: key, value: "\(value)".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed))
            urlComponents.queryItems?.append(queryItem)
        }

        urlRequest.url = urlComponents.url
    }

    if urlRequest.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") == nil {
        urlRequest.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: Any logic to achieve what you say would need to be able to handle nested dictionaries. How do you plan to encode those?

Comment: @Cristik yes i understand did think about that too. Its complicated.

Comment: Why not just pass JSON data in the request body rather than trying to code everything as URL parameters? It will be much simpler and easily extensible. I can post sample code for this if you'd like.

Comment: @JonJ because this is what the api needs. And its something that i cannot change for now. It is not even a post request. It is a get request with query parameters in the url.

Comment: That's understood, but it sounds like it's a poorly designed API. GET requests are just that - GET data rather than POST data.

Comment: @JonJ thats true but im unfortunately stuck with it for now